# PHP Array sorting by Date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

I have this table:

```
Date | Tobic | Speaker

25.01.2013 | My topic one | my speaker one
28.05.2017 | My topic two | my speaker two
03.02.2014 | My topic three | my speaker three
```

How do I load this in an array, sort it by date and then print it out?

Comment: Use PDO(http://bobby-tables.com/) for database access and echo for output. More than happy to help with errors in your code. But we cannot write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The below should output the table in grouped by date then just do a order by

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT date,topic,speaker FROM table');
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE));
```

Just a concept; did not test but an idea of how to

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `strtotime()` for converting a string to a timestamp and `ksort()` to sort an array by keys.

```
$myPodcasts;

//loop at all rows of a table
foreach ($allFiles as $file) {
     $myPodcasts[] = array(
       'date' => strtotime('25.01.2013'),
       'topic' => 'My topic one',
       'speaker' => 'My Speaker one'
   );
} 

//Sort array by keys
ksort($myPodcasts);
```

Sort possibilities

```
•sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
•rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
•asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
•ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
•arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
•krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```